# How to break a string in URL by using CSS

Tags: css

Good morning,

I have a menu with a few options. I want to display an image and next to it a string, menu hyperlink. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="category" id="category-19">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost/new.domain/test-test" data-depth="0">
            ::before
            Test Test
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
#header .menu, #header .menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#_desktop_top_menu a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top-menu a[data-depth="0"] {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: .1875rem .625rem .375rem;
}
.dropdown-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px 1.5rem;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #373a3c;
    text-align: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
}
```

I Want to have something like that:

[image]

How to get this effect ? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<pre>` tag before Test and close it.

The  tag defines preformatted text.

Comment: How ? Could You give a an example ?

Comment: <pre>
Test
Test
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

You can force-wrap be giving it a fixed size and using word-wrap:

```
.dropdown-item { 
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```